# Como fazer um contorno em texto via CSS

Tags: css, texto

Pessoal alguém pode me ajudar a fazer esse contorno em texto pelo css

[image: Texto com contorno em css]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode usar `-webkit-text-stroke`, mas não tem suporte para o IE:

```
<style>
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px; /* largura da borda */
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #000; /* cor da borda */
</style>
```

```css
.borda_texto{
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: #000;
font-size: 3em; color: #fffdd9;
}
```

```html
<div class="borda_texto">
    Contorno no texto
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Outra forma de fazer esse efeito é colocando o texto dentro de um SVG e usar a propriedade `stroke-width` no texto. O ideal é que vc construa o `viewBox` direitinho pro seu SVG para poder aplicar sem dor de cabeça, mas fica o exemplo ai.

```html
<svg>
  <text x="0" y="60px" font-size="60px" style="fill: white; stroke: black; stroke-width: 2px">
    Exemplo
  </text>  
<text x="0" y="120px" font-size="60px" style="fill: red; stroke: blue; stroke-width: 3px; font-family: sans-serif">
    Exemplo 2
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar:

```
text-shadow: 2px 2px black;
```

Comment: se possível sempre coloque um exemplo ou imagem do resultado do código

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
 .sombra {text-shadow:#000 -1px -1px}
</style>
```

ou

```
<style>
     .borda {color:#FFCCAC; text-shadow:#000 1px -1px, #000 -1px 1px, #000 1px 1px, #000 -1px -1px}
</style>
```

Comment: o seu deu certo mas eu queria que a borda fosse como mostra na imagem acima bem maior

Comment: É só aumentar o valor de pixels (px)...

Comment: mas qual deles por favor

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela ajuda

Comment: me passa o site que vc viu esse texto

Comment: Você fala da imagem que eu postei?

Comment: isso desta imagem

Comment: brother não foi de site nenhum, eu criei essa imagem pelo photoscape para usar como exemplo, mas tem esse exemplo aqui http://www.paolawilm.com.br/css-borda-e-texto/ mas a borda ta muito fina eu tentei aumentar essa borda e não consegui

Comment: O exemplo que nosso amigo postou abaixo funciona

Comment: Sim obrigado pela ajuda, vcs são feras nisso

Answer (score -3):

```
.text-custom {
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 4px; /* largura da borda */
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black; /* cor da borda */
    -webkit-text-fill-color: white;
}
```